# Belkin thunderbold docking station with external monitor not working on macbook pro with Fedora 24?

Tags: macintosh, monitors, multi-monitor, hot-plug

I have a Macbook pro (late 2015) with a Belkin thunderbolt docking station.
On that docking station, I have a screen connected to it via (mini) DisplayPort, along with other items (keyboard, mouse, sound).

When I'm under Mac OS (Sierra), the docking station works like a charm. The external monitor is well detected and works correctly.

If I boot under Fedora 24 (64bit), and I plug the docking station. Every elements (keyboard, mouse and sound) works correctly but the screen is never detected.

I've tried to connect the screen directly to the Mac (still via the miniDP) and this time, it works correctly. So it's apparently from the docking station that the issue is causing.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

When I plug the screen on the docking station and watch dmesg, here's what appears :

```
[nov.14 00:58] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: resetting error on 1:b.
[  +0,000064] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: 1:b: got unplug event for disconnected port, ignoring
[  +0,656809] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: resetting error on 1:a.
[  +0,000031] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: 1:a: hotplug: scanning
[  +0,000003] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: 1:a: hotplug: no switch found
```

Same message appears when I turn on/off the screen.